# Why can't I delete a comment on a Question which is on hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, comments

I like to delete comments after a few days, so that I don't contribute to our 
"Comments Problem".

But I can't delete any comment when the associated question is On Hold or locked. Thus, I end up with a batch of un-deletable comments like [Could Wearing My Star of David Be Bad for Career?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56847/could-wearing-my-star-of-david-be-bad-for-career#comment147155_56847).

I'm wondering why the delete feature works this way? A bug? A feature? Can it be changed? Seems odd to me.

Comment: @NormalHuman - hmm. I can't delete http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/56847/could-wearing-my-star-of-david-be-bad-for-career#comment147155_56847 and the question is On Hold.

Answer (score 3):

Questions which are migrated *to* here but get closed end up locked (feature? bug?). It is considered a rejected migration.

Most of our locked questions are locked as a result of this.

Locked questions prevent everything. Edits, comments, deleting, flagging, etc.

---

As an FYI, too, regarding locked questions, they are hard to really do anything with because of this. If there are questions you feel could be edited into on-topic feel free to post them either on meta or in chat. As moderators we can unlock them (even rejected migrations).

Comment: I had not noticed that the star-of-david question was locked, and I've just unlocked it.  In particular, it's unfortunate that it was blocked from edits -- sorry folks; didn't notice.